# I can't access objects from a many to many field

Tags: python, django

I cant access the objects of a many to many field on my template, whereas i can access the objects of other fields

`models.py`

```
class Cart(models.Model):
 total = models.IntegerField(max_length=None, default=0)
 timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
 updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
 active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
 products = models.ManyToManyField(product)
```

`views.py`

```
def carthome(request):
    cartproduct = Cart.objects.all()
    print(cartproduct)
    context = { 'cartproduct' : cartproduct, }
    return render(request, 'home/carthome.html', context)
```

in templates

```
{% for abc in cartproduct%}
{{ abc.product.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Error

```
AttributeError: 'Cart' object has no attribute 'product'
```

Comment: You called it `products` yet trying to use it using `.product`. Also, this is a many to many relation, meaning that there will be multiple products. You must loop through them.

Comment: the products was a typo into stack overflow it's products in my code. and i tried using a for loop in the template didn't work. Also tried indexing the first element in the carthome views; also didn't work

Comment: I believe that `products` abstractly give you a list, not an object so.. try with adding another for loop inside `for abc in cartproduct`, like so: `{% for abc in cartproduct  %}{% for product in abc.products %}{{product.name}}{% endfor %}{% endfor %}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model you have  products = models.ManyToManyField(product). 
make sure that in product model you have name atribute. then try this code

```
{% for abc in cartproduct%}
{{ abc.products.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

seems in your code you are trying directly to reach product model. but you should  get it through Cart(cartproduct) then products(which is Cart atribute) then name.

Answer (score 0):

`Cart.objects.all()` will give you all `Cart`s. Either loop over all of them in the template (though I doubt that's what you want to do), or pick one.

`cart = Cart.objects.first()` or `cart = Cart.objects.get(id=1)` or whatever gives you just one cart (so no `filter()`).

Then `cartproducts = cart.products.all()` should fix it. The template is ok, net of the typo (cartproduct -> cartproduct**s**).

---

Also, and this is widely off topic: how will you manage quantities in your cart? Product has no quantities, and Cart only holds products. You'll be stuck to only single quantities products, unless you make a separate model with `ForeignKeys` `cart`, `product` and `IntegerField` quantity.

Comment: def carthome(request):
    cart = Cart.objects.first()
    print(cart.products)
    context = { 'cart' : cart, }


    return render(request, 'home/carthome.html', context)  # returned home.product.None

Comment: cart.products.*all()*

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort through both your model objects and *then* your manytomany field - the option mentioned below will work.

```
{% for x in cartproduct %}
{% for y in x.products.all %}
{{ y }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  Add an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Since `ManyToMany` field may contain multiple items so you need to loop through them.

For example:

```
{% for abc in cartproduct %}
{% for product in abc.products.all %}

{{product.name}}

{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %} # this if condition is to separate the products with comma

{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```